# Eliminating duplication code from webtool

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-ui, google-app-engine

I'm building a web tool and i have a lot of windows. As of now I have it plain HTML but want to optimize it. Here the code: I have over 10 of these with similar frames.

```
<div id="test" class="panel draggable">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <h3>test</h3>
        <div class="close" title="Close test window">&times;</div>
        <div class="sizing" style="display:none" title="Show the content">+</div>
        <div class="sizing" title="Hide the content">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content placeholder">
      // Any content here, from table,iframe,images...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using python (Google App Engine) JQuery / JS / HTML / CSS

Comment: In what way do you want to optimize it?

Comment: So I dont have to write all the html for each window, possible a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to start using a web framework. If you're comfortable with python try looking into [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).